# Aiml values not matching

Tags: chatbot, aiml

In aiml i am not getting the condition values which i have assigned. i'm getting unknown answers here is my code:

```
<category>
    <pattern>ask me question</pattern>
    <template>
 let look <srai>QUESTION</srai>
</template>
</category>

<category>
    <that>let look *</that>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <template>
      
      <think>
          <set name="letlook"><star/></set>
      </think>
      
          <condition name="letlook">
            <li>no that is not right</li>
            <li value="phone"><think><set name="letlook">phone</set></think> right</li>
        </condition>
        </template>
</category>


<category>
    <pattern>QUESTION</pattern>
    <template>
        What never asks a question but gets answered all the time?
          <think>
<set name="letlook">phone</set></think>
</template>
</category>
```

i want it to respond like this

```
Human: ask me question
Robot: What never asks a question but gets answered all the time?
Human: Phone
Robot: Right
```

but i am getting this response

```
Human: ask me question
Robot: What never asks a question but gets answered all the time?
Human: Phone
Robot: no that is not right
```

How to fix this code? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list items in conditions are matched from top to bottom. Your condition will always produce the first answer, as you haven't provided a value, and so it always matches. Swap the `<li>` elements around and it will work.

```
    <condition name="letlook">
        <li value="phone"><think><set name="letlook">phone</set></think> right</li>
        <li>no that is not right</li>
    </condition>
```

Oh, and you don't need to set "letlook" to "phone" in your li as it will already have that value.

Comment: Thank you it really worked! i have one more query if user responses "I think the answer is phone" then the value will not matched only "phone" value will match how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You will need to create a few more li  lines like this: <li value="* phone">

Comment: Thank you once again. actually I've added same li lines as you mentioned but they were <li value="* phone *"> which didn't worked.